# Fragment Flow in View Pager in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using viewPager for tabs in my application . I have 2 Tabs  and both tabs are making network call. As view pager inflate the both fragment in the starting so I created a interface and implemented in both fragment with a function onRefresh() which is basically doing the network call. Now issue which I am facing is, When I put my app in the background on 2nd tab and resume the application, it is calling the network api of first tab not the second tab.

I want the API of tab to be called which was visible when I put the app in the background.

Can any one tell me how can I achieve it?

Comment: show me your work first

Comment: I have achieved it by getting the current item from pager and then call the API for corresponding item.

Comment: ok.... :-) nice work